# c fscanf using and new line

Tags: c, scanf

I need to receive and put into variables text file.
For example:

```
/*
system_1
6
challenge_2 22 2
challenge_3 33 3
challenge_4 44 1
challenge_5 55 3
challenge_6 66 3
challenge_1 11 1
4
room_2 1 22
room_1 3 11 44 66
room_3 3 55 33 11
room_4 4 22 44 55 66
*/
```

I know that every one of the words (not line) is not more than 50 characters.
What will be the easy way to put each word in the appropriate (int,string...).
Also I need to know where the line is ending because the number of words in line is not constant.
I think fscanf is the most efficient, but I dont know how to use it for line ending and such... 
I would love to see an example of using fscanf as I wanted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to read the manual page for `fscanf`? Also provide some code that you have tried

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't understand how the function handle with spaces between each word and new line.

Comment: What do you not understand with _A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input. _

Comment: `challenge_n` lines seems to be fixed number of items. Also, `room_n` lines seems to be given the number of items beforehand, right?

Comment: *"I need to receive and put into variables text file. For example:"* Your example gives insufficient information to form a valid specification. Please provide further requirements regarding the file format. Namely: 1/ Is it guaranteed that the first "word" is always to be stored as a string, and never as an `int`? 2/ Similarly, are all of the other fields guaranteed to be `int` values represented as decimal digit sequences?

Comment: @seb - I was answering his comment.

Comment: 3/ Is it guaranteed that the spaces between fields will be precisely 1 space?

Comment: @EdHeal My bad... I failed to notice that correlation.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, it is

Comment: @Seb 1. except the lines that have one number, all the others lines start with a string and never as an int. 2. Yes, all int.

Comment: @Seb Yes, spaces will be one

Comment: @user7418143 Ahh, I see. That lone number is the number of `challenge_n` items and `room_n` items that follow it respectfully. This information is expected within your question.

Comment: @user7418143 If that is right, there is nothing difficult. Are `/*` and `*/` included in the file?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do you mean by /* and */? if you mean remarks in the file so no.

Comment: @user7418143 - Then please edit the question to include the actual file i.e. without `/*`

Comment: @user7418143 So like [this](http://ideone.com/lR0K9Z) Please add the necessary check afterwards.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Wow! Thanks!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The only problem is that as you can see in the text I dont know then number of parameters each room have (the integer parameters is not constant). So how can I make sure that each parameter will get to the correct room? (I need to know where the line is ending). And last question, if I have main program and in the main program I will open the file and send the file each time to Auxiliary functions, Is the file start each function in the start, or will continue from the point the read is ending? Thanks!

Comment: _each parameter will get to the correct room?_ `data.room[index].n`. You use such as `void loadFromFile(Data *data, const char *filename);` at first. Then use `Type Auxiliary_functions(Data *data){ ... };` (E.g `Data data; loadFromFile(&data, "data.txt");  Auxiliary_functions(&data);`)

Comment: You should *try* writing this code yourself, rather than expecting us to write it. The requirements you gave as answers to my question make it *very difficult*, as `fscanf` reads *fields*, not *lines*, and many of those *fields* implicitly discard prefixed whitespace (e.g. `%d` will cause `"   \n   \t1234"` to convert to `1234`). Also see [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score -1):

It's more efficient, because you do not know the format string to use fgets to return a line from the file, then to parse it yourself rather than using scanf.

An example would be like this:

```
FILE* file = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
char buffer[51];
while (fgets(buffer, 50, file)) {
    // Buffer now stores the line, lets see if it can be an integer.
    int possible_num = 0;
    // sscanf will return 1 if it read a possible integer from the buffer.
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &possible_num) == 1) {
        // We read a number, so possible_num is now the number.
    }
    else {
        // We read a string, buffer stores the string.
    }
}
```

NOTE: The code will return a false positive if your string is something like "10hello", as sscanf will still read the 10. There are multiple ways of checking if  a string is  a valid integer out there in C, which I'm sure you will be able to find on StackOverflow, but this code should give you a place to get started.

Comment: You should check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: PS: `fscanf` uses buffer input  - just as efficient as the code you have given

Comment: Perhaps more efficient on the machine, due to the lack of intermediate `buffer` required for `%d` parses.